# Mixing radio with checked button in html

Tags: html

I want to mix radio and checked button like i design B here https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/70531/using-mixed-radio-and-checkbox-buttons-is-there-any-efficiency-or-usability-ga

But i just could figure out how to do separately:

```
<input class="radio-input" type="radio" name="result" value="names" />
<label class="radio-label">Get names of people starting with..</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="A" name="name[]" value="n">
<label for="A">A</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="B" name="name[]" value="n">
<label for="B">B</label>
```

How can i do this like in design B?

Comment: ...So what is your **question**?

Comment: Sorry @ObsidianAge i edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to put them into separate divs, and then align them to be next to each other with CSS styling.

```css
.no-bullets {
  list-style:none;
}
```

```html
   
  <h2>first row</h1>


  <ul class = "no-bullets">
    <li> <input type="radio" name="name"></li>
    <li> <input type="radio" name="name"></li>
    
    <ul class = "no-bullets">  
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="sex"></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="sex"></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="sex"></li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: how can i do that in css?

Comment: @1pa I showed you how to do this without CSS, but they will have dots by them because they are list items, you can turn this off with CSS.

Edited to show you how to do this.

Comment: Thank you! i accepted this answer as the correct one